# Difficulty about Jordan decomposition, (and also an ambiguity about the quadratic forms in indecomposable Jordan components of quadratic modules)

Tags: gr.group-theory, linear-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, modular-forms, p-adic-analysis

I am trying to understand a concept through solving some exercises, but I can't solve one of them, and I need a hint and guide.

I asked my questions in the boxes (See the end of this question). (**I think that I solved 14.17., and I write my attempt at the end, but I have some doubts about that**)

These are exercises 14.17. and 14.18., in the last section of Chapter 14 of the book "Modular Forms, A Classical Approach, by Henri Cohen and Fredrik Stromberg":

**Exercise 14.17.** With notation as in **Lemma 14.5.3** show that:
(i) If $p > 2$, then $\underline{A}^t_{p^k}$ is the discriminant form of the lattice $\mathbb{Z}_p \subseteq \mathbb{Q}_p$ with quadratic form $Q(x) = p^kt^{−1}x^2$ where $t^{-1}$ is the inverse of $t \mod p$. (Hint: $p^{−k}\mathbb{Z}_p/\mathbb{Z}_p \cong \mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}_p$.)

**Exercise 14.18.** Use an explicit isomorphism between $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ to show that the discriminant form of the lattice $L = \mathbb{Z}$ with quadratic form $Q(x) = 3x^2$ has Jordan decomposition $D \cong \underline{A}^1_{3} \oplus \underline{A}^3_{2}$.

**Some concepts appeared in the exercises**: In this book the Gram matrix of a quadratic form is twice the Gram matrix in most of the books (as you know it doesn't affect the theory), in other words if we denote the Gram matrix of the quadratic form $Q(X)$ (again) by $Q$, then we mean a symmetric matrix $Q$ such that $Q(X)=\frac{1}{2}X^tQX$. Also the Bilinear form is twice the bilinear form in most of the books (as you know it doesn't affect the theory), and
$$B(X, Y)=Q(X+Y)-Q(X)-Q(Y)=X^tQY.$$
Assume that $L$ is an even lattice, or equivalently that $Q$ is an integral quadratic form on $L$, in other words, that $Q(X) \in \mathbb{Z}$ for all $X \in L$, and define the dual lattice of $L$ with respect to $Q$ by
$L^*= \{Y ∈ \mathbb{R}^n : B(X, Y) \in \mathbb{Z} \ \ for \ all \ \ X \in L \}$,
and since $Q$ is integral, we have $L \subseteq L∗$. It is easy to see that $L^∗/L$ is a finite abelian group, which is called the **discriminant form of $L$**. Also we need another definition, the definition of a quadratic module:

Let $D$ be a finite abelian group and $Q : D → \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ a quadratic form with nondegenerate bilinear form $B(x, y) = Q(x + y) − Q(x) − Q(y)$. The tuple $\underline{D} = (D,Q)$ is said to be a finite quadratic module.

**Lemma 14.5.3**: You can see Lemma 14.5.3 in the following image, and that's the reason why I am trying to solve this exercise:
[image]

**My attempts**: $Q(x) = p^kt^{−1}x^2$, and $B(x,y)=2p^kt^{−1}xy$

$$L^*= \{y ∈ \mathbb{Q}_p : B(x, y) \in \mathbb{Z}_p \ \ for \ all \ \ x \in \mathbb{Z}_p \} \\ 
= \{y ∈ \mathbb{Q}_p : k+v_p(x)+v_p(y)=v_p(2)+k-v_p(t)+v_p(x)+v_p(y)=v_p(2p^kt^{−1}xy) \geq 0, \ \forall x \in \mathbb{Z}_p \} \\ 
= \{y ∈ \mathbb{Q}_p : k+v_p(y) \geq 0 \} 
= p^{−k}\mathbb{Z}_p, $$
and that well-known isomorphism shows that the discriminant form $D=L^*/L$ is precisely $\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}_p$. It is easy to see that $Q(x/p^k)=\frac{t^{-1}x^2}{p^k} + \mathbb{Z}$, and since $t$ is invertible in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, the quadratic form $\frac{t^{-1}x^2}{p^k}$ is $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p\mathbb{Z}}$-equivalent to $t^2\frac{t^{-1}x^2}{p^k}=\frac{tx^2}{p^k}$. The same argument works for the rest of 14.17., for example, for $\underline{A}^t_{2^k}$, the same process must be repeated for $P(x) = 2^{k-1}t^{−1}x^2 (k \geq 1)$.

**Now I will write about my misunderstandings and ambiguities**:
Let $u \in \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p\mathbb{Z}}$ be a unit, then the quadratic form appearing in $\underline{A}^t_{p^k}$ in Lemma 14.5.3 ($x \mapsto tx^2/p^k + \mathbb{Z}$) is $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p\mathbb{Z}}$-equivalent to $\frac{u^2tx^2}{p^k}$, and we can replace it with the quadratic form in the lemma. My first question is

> 1. Is my attempt to exercise 14.17. correct?

> 2. If my proof is true, then we can replace $\frac{tx^2}{p^k}$(the quadratic form in the lemma) with $\frac{u^2tx^2}{p^k}$. Why did we choose that representative in the lemma? We could start with the quadratic form $Q(x) = p^ktx^2$, and the same argument works and we came to the same quadratic module. So why did we start from $Q(x) = p^kt^{−1}x^2$?

> 3. In exercise 14.18., it is easy to write down an explicit isomorphism, but right now I don't have any idea how to go further, and I can't solve it. What is the Jordan decomposition if we replace the quadratic form with $px^2$ or $pqx^2$ (where $p$ and $q$ are odd primes)? I can only say that we should consider the remainders of $p$ and $q$ module $8$.